# Cannot test ILogger<T> Received with NSubstitute

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, mstest, nsubstitute, ilogger

I have a .Net Core 3 application and am trying to test calls to ILogger in my method:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;

    public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void MyMethod(string message)
    {
        _logger.LogError(message);
    }
}
```

Having found answers here on SO and on blogs, I know that I have to test against the interface method, not the extension method, so I have this test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyMethodTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger<MyClass>>();

    var myClass = new MyClass(logger);

    var message = "a message";

    // Act
    myClass.MyMethod(message);

    // Assert
    logger.Received(1).Log(
        LogLevel.Error,
        Arg.Any<EventId>(),
        Arg.Is<object>(o => o.ToString() == message),
        null,
        Arg.Any<Func<object, Exception, string>>());
}
```

However, this isn't working and I get this error:

```
Test method MyLibrary.Tests.MyClassTests.MyMethodTest threw exception: 
NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException: Expected to receive exactly 1 call matching:
    Log<Object>(Error, any EventId, o => (o.ToString() == value(MyLibrary.Tests.MyClassTests+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).message), <null>, any Func<Object, Exception, String>)
Actually received no matching calls.

    at NSubstitute.Core.ReceivedCallsExceptionThrower.Throw(ICallSpecification callSpecification, IEnumerable`1 matchingCalls, IEnumerable`1 nonMatchingCalls, Quantity requiredQuantity)
   at NSubstitute.Routing.Handlers.CheckReceivedCallsHandler.Handle(ICall call)
   at NSubstitute.Routing.Route.Handle(ICall call)
   at NSubstitute.Core.CallRouter.Route(ICall call)
   at NSubstitute.Proxies.CastleDynamicProxy.CastleForwardingInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at NSubstitute.Proxies.CastleDynamicProxy.ProxyIdInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
   at MyLibrary.Tests.MyClassTests.MyMethodTest() in D:\Source\Scratch\MyLibrary\MyLibrary.Tests\MyClassTests.cs:line 25
```

What am I doing wrong?

netcoreapp3.0 / Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 3.1.2 / NSubstitute 4.2.1

**UPDATE:** I have tried the match with `Arg.Any<>()` and get the same result:

```
logger.Received(1).Log(
    Arg.Any<LogLevel>(),
    Arg.Any<EventId>(),
    Arg.Any<object>(),
    Arg.Any<Exception>(),
    Arg.Any<Func<object, Exception, string>>());
```

**UPDATE 2:** I have tried the same test using Moq and get the same result:

```
logger.Verify(l => l.Log(
        LogLevel.Error,
        It.IsAny<EventId>(),
        It.Is<object>(o => o.ToString() == message),
        null,
        It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>()),
    Times.Once);
```

Result:

```
Test method MyLibrary.Tests.Moq.MyClassTests.MyMethodTest threw exception: 
Moq.MockException: 
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: l => l.Log<object>(LogLevel.Error, It.IsAny<EventId>(), It.Is<object>(o => o.ToString() == "a message"), null, It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>())

Performed invocations:

   Mock<ILogger<MyClass>:1> (l):

      ILogger.Log<FormattedLogValues>(LogLevel.Error, 0, a message, null, Func<FormattedLogValues, Exception, string>)

    at Moq.Mock.Verify(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Times times, String failMessage)
   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify(Expression`1 expression, Times times)
   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify(Expression`1 expression, Func`1 times)
   at MyLibrary.Tests.Moq.MyClassTests.MyMethodTest() in D:\Source\Scratch\MyLibrary\MyLibrary.Tests.Moq\MyClassTests.cs:line 25
```

Comment: Your code calls `LogError()`, while you're verifying a call to `Log()`...

Comment: `LogError` is an extension method which eventually chains down to `Log` - as I said, this is the example code given in many blog posts and on other SO questions

Comment: e.g. https://codeburst.io/unit-testing-with-net-core-ilogger-t-e8c16c503a80#0b05

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54809607/243189

Comment: See https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/597#issuecomment-573742574

Comment: @haim770 thanks for that... it certainly sheds light but I'm not sure how to proceed... Use the somehow working verification on the static extension, or wrap ILogger in my own interface... both are not good options. The MELT solution looks interesting but in my full implementation I am actually using AutoFixture.Freeze so not sure its appropriate

Comment: please add the link as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I've gone with the "head in the sand" option and testing against the extensions. I'll worry about it when/if tests break in the future

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The main issue unit testing ILogger invocations with .NET Core 3.* is that `FormattedLogValues` was changed to internal, it complicates things.

The Moq workaround is to use `It.IsAnyType`:

```
public class TestsUsingMoq
{
    [Test]
    public void MyMethod_String_LogsError()
    {
        // Arrange
        var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<MyClass>>();

        var myClass = new MyClass(logger);

        var message = "a message";

        // Act
        myClass.MyMethod(message);

        //Assert
        Mock.Get(logger)
            .Verify(l => l.Log(LogLevel.Error,
                    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                    It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((o, t) => ((IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>) o).Last().Value.ToString().Equals(message)),
                    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                    (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>) It.IsAny<object>()),
                Times.Once);
    }
}
```

NSubstitute doesn't have an `It.IsAnyType` equivalent at the moment as far as I am aware, which presents an issue when trying to use the `Received` method. There is a workaround however as it does provide a `ReceivedCalls` method which you can iterate over and do you own invocation check.

```
public class TestsUsingNSubstitute
{
    [Test]
    public void MyMethod_String_LogsError()
    {
        // Arrange
        var logger = Substitute.For<ILogger<MyClass>>();

        var myClass = new MyClass(logger);

        var message = "a message";

        // Act
        myClass.MyMethod(message);

        //Assert
        Assert.That(logger.ReceivedCalls()
                .Select(call => call.GetArguments())
                .Count(callArguments => ((LogLevel) callArguments[0]).Equals(LogLevel.Error) &&
                                        ((IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>) callArguments[2]).Last().Value.ToString().Equals(message)),
            Is.EqualTo(1));
    }
}
```

As a workaround, it's not a bad one, and could be easily bundled up into an extension method.

`FormattedLogValues` implements `IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`. The last item in this list is the original message that you specified.

[Working sample](https://github.com/rgvlee/StackOverflow/tree/master/Question60684578)

Comment: Congrats, it is just perfect :-) The very low attention for this topic proves the sad fact, that developers rarely unit testing against logging specification/expectation. Otherwise should be millions of developers would landing here in the last few years and upvote this answer.

Comment: We had to tweak this slightly due to using templating in our logs so we just simplified the second part of the Count to be `callArguments[2].ToString().Equals(message)`

Answer (score 1):

I tried wrapping the Logger around an adapter, more like a proxy class.
You can mock the adapter interface and that would return what log function has been called.

```
 public class LoggerAdapter<TType> : ILoggerAdapter<TType>
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TType> _logger;

        public LoggerAdapter(ILogger<TType> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public void LogInformation(string message, params object[] args)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(message,args);
        }

        public void LogError(string message, params object[] args)
        {
            _logger.LogError(message, args);
        }
    }
```

```
 private readonly ILoggerAdapter<PosUpdateService> _logger = Substitute.For<ILoggerAdapter<PosUpdateService>>();
```

```
_logger.Received(1).LogInformation("User with Id {id} was fetched in {0} milliseconds", 
               Arg.Is(Id),
               Arg.Any<long>());
```