# Does NSubstitute have anything like It.IsAnyType in Moq now?

Tags: c#, moq, nsubstitute

I am trying to use nsubstitute to test the ILogger in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.
Just as here says:
[Cannot test ILogger<T> Received with NSubstitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684578/cannot-test-iloggert-received-with-nsubstitute)
, at that time, nsubstitute has no something like **It.IsAnyType** in Moq, I want to know whether nsubstitute has the similar thing now? as I am also work on unit test based on nsubstitute.
@rgvlee's sample:

```
public class TestsUsingMoq
{
    [Test]
    public void MyMethod_String_LogsError()
    {
        // Arrange
        var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<MyClass>>();

        var myClass = new MyClass(logger);

        var message = "a message";

        // Act
        myClass.MyMethod(message);

        //Assert
        Mock.Get(logger)
            .Verify(l => l.Log(LogLevel.Error,
                    It.IsAny<EventId>(),
                    It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((o, t) => ((IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>) o).Last().Value.ToString().Equals(message)),
                    It.IsAny<Exception>(),
                    (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>) It.IsAny<object>()),
                Times.Once);
    }
}
```

I tried to do similar thing in my code by nsubstitute, but it's failed, as (Arg.Is<-object->) does not equal **It.Is<It.IsAnyType>** in moq.

```
           _logger.IsEnabled(Arg.Any<LogLevel>()).Returns(true);

            _logger.Received().Log(
                Arg.Any<LogLevel>(),
                Arg.Any<EventId>(),
                Arg.Is<object>(o => o.ToString().Contains("bad")),
                null,
                Arg.Any<Func<object, Exception, string>>());
```

Comment: No NSubstitute does not have a matcher for any generic type like `IsAnyType`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from version 5.1.0 NSubstitute supports **Arg.AnyType** for matching calls with generic parameters.
https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/releases/tag/v5.1.0

Comment: Is there any example where Arg.AnyType is used? I don't seem to be able to mock something like "TItem Set<TItem>(object key, TItem value)" to return the TItem value

Comment: It seems the current release of NSubstitute supports only the argument matching using Arg.AnyType. I would suggest opening an issue for this case.

Answer (score 0):

A potential workaround is to fetch the call information and process it manually. For example:

```
// Assuming this object contains the expected key-value pairs that are logged:
var expectedLogState = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

loggerMock.ReceivedCalls().Should().NotBeEmpty();
var logInput = loggerMock.ReceivedCalls().First().GetArguments();
logInput[0].Should().Be(LogLevel.Error);
(logInput[2] as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>).Should().Contain(expectedLogState);
```