# Test ILogger with FakeItEasy

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy, ilogger

I'm working on a fun project for myself to learn blazor, a lot of core concepts and just general practice.

I'm trying to implement logger extension for FakeItEasy to easier test Microsofts ILogger.
Based on https://dev.azure.com/BrideButler/Bride%20Butler%20Open%20Source/_git/FakeItEasy.DotnetCore.LoggerExtensions?path=%2FFakeItEasy.DotnetCore.LoggerExtensions%2FLoggerExtensions.cs but now trying to get it to work for .NET 5.
Now that `FormattedLogValues` is internal this code doesn't work anymore.

The goal is to have something like this in my test (and not use Moq)
 `_logger.VerifyLog(LogLevel.Information, "Get Weather Called").MustHaveHappenedOnceExactly();`
or `A.CallTo(() => _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Get Weather Called").MustHaveHappenedOnceExactly();` It doesn't have to have syntactic sugar but I would like to get it to work with FakeItEasy instead of Moq.

Below is all the involved code. Ofcourse I see some difference in the first line `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.Log`1[System.Object]`vs`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Server.Controllers.WeatherForecastController].Log`1[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.FormattedLogValues]` but I've no clue how to "fix" this since I dont fully understand what is going wrong.

My question is obviously, what should I do to fix it, but also curious what part i'm missing.

My error is the following:

```
  Assertion failed for the following call:
        Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.Log`1[System.Object]
        (
            logLevel: Information,
            eventId: <Ignored>, 
            state: <e => e.ToString().Contains(value(Server.Tests.Extensions.LoggerExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1[Server.Controllers.WeatherForecastController]).message)>,
            exception: <Ignored>, 
            formatter: <Ignored>
        )
      Expected to find it once exactly but didn't find it among the calls:
        1: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Server.Controllers.WeatherForecastController].Log`1[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.FormattedLogValues]
        (
            logLevel: Information,
            eventId: 0,
            state: [[{OriginalFormat}, Get Weather Called]],
            exception: NULL,
            formatter: System.Func`3[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.FormattedLogValues,System.Exception,System.String]
      )
```

Tests:
(using xUnit, FakeItEasy, Fixture)

LoggerExtensions

```
public static class LoggerExtensions
    {
        public static void VerifyLogMustHaveHappened<T>(this ILogger<T> logger, LogLevel level, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                logger.VerifyLog(level, message)
                    .MustHaveHappened();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new ExpectationException($"while verifying a call to log with message: \"{message}\"", e);
            }
        }

        public static void VerifyLogMustNotHaveHappened<T>(this ILogger<T> logger, LogLevel level, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                logger.VerifyLog(level, message)
                    .MustNotHaveHappened();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new ExpectationException($"while verifying a call to log with message: \"{message}\"", e);
            }
        }

        public static IVoidArgumentValidationConfiguration VerifyLog<T>(this ILogger<T> logger, LogLevel level,
            string message)
        {
            return A.CallTo(() => logger.Log(
                    level, 
                    A<EventId>._,
                    A<object>.That.Matches(e => e.ToString().Contains(message)),
                    A<Exception>._,
                    A<Func<object, Exception, string>>._)
                );
        }
    }
```

TestConstructor:

```
private readonly IFixture _fixture;
private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

public WeatherForecastControllerTests()
{
    _fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoFakeItEasyCustomization());
    _logger = _fixture.Freeze<Fake<ILogger<WeatherForecastController>>>().FakedObject;
}
```

Test:

```
[Fact]
public void WeatherForecast_Get_Should_Log()
{
    // Arrange
    var weatherController = new WeatherForecastController(_logger);

    // Act
    weatherController.Get();

    // Assert
    _logger.VerifyLog(LogLevel.Information, "Get Weather Called").MustHaveHappenedOnceExactly();
}
```

Controller:

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        // Left out other code then logging
        _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Get Weather Called");
    }
}
```

Update:
**Options found**

Only test if logger was called with correct log level:

```
   public static IVoidArgumentValidationConfiguration VerifyLog<T>(this ILogger<T> logger, LogLevel level, string message)
        {
            return A.CallTo(logger).Where(call => call.Method.Name == "Log" && call.GetArgument<LogLevel>(0) == level);
        }
```

Switch to Moq:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59182490/1112413
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56728528/1112413
```

Comment: Your error says that `formatter` delegate (the last parameter in `Log` method) is expected to be `Func<FormattedLogValues, Exception, string>`. But you are using `Func<object, Exception, string>` here, it might an issue

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thank you for explaining. I made a work around due to understanding the error with your comment.

Answer (score 8):

After reading https://stackoverflow.com/users/4728685/pavel-anikhouski comment on the post. I "got" what was wrong. Went to countless topics and made a solution that "works" tho probably could use some better coding standards. Hope it helps anyone else!

Edit: Some explaining.

Found [this](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/1650#issuecomment-539463902) github comment that is the base of the solution. Then found [this](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow/pull/338) github pr where they mentioned to change `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.FormattedLogValues` to `IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`
This can be extracted from `GetArgument(2)`. (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63701968/1112413)

```
  public static class LoggerExtensions
    {
        public static void VerifyLogMustHaveHappened<T>(this ILogger<T> logger, LogLevel level, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                logger.VerifyLog(level, message)
                    .MustHaveHappened();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new ExpectationException($"while verifying a call to log with message: \"{message}\"", e);
            }
        }

        public static void VerifyLogMustNotHaveHappened<T>(this ILogger<T> logger, LogLevel level, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                logger.VerifyLog(level, message)
                    .MustNotHaveHappened();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new ExpectationException($"while verifying a call to log with message: \"{message}\"", e);
            }
        }

        public static IVoidArgumentValidationConfiguration VerifyLog<T>(this ILogger<T> logger, LogLevel level, string message)
        {
            return A.CallTo(logger)
                .Where(call => call.Method.Name == "Log" 
                    && call.GetArgument<LogLevel>(0) == level 
                    && CheckLogMessages(call.GetArgument<IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>>(2), message));
        }

        private static bool CheckLogMessages(IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>> readOnlyLists, string message)
        {
            foreach(var kvp in readOnlyLists)
            {
                if (kvp.Value.ToString().Contains(message))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the [same comments of Github](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/1650#issuecomment-539463902)

I ended up with a solution like that:

```
public class MyClassWithLoggerTests
{
    private readonly MyClassWithLogger _sut;
    private readonly ILogger<MyClassWithLogger> _logger;

    public MyClassWithLoggerTests()
    {
        this._logger = A.Fake<ILogger<MyClassWithLogger>>();
        this._sut = new MyClassWithLogger(this._logger);
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public ATestMethodTitle()
    {
        this._sut.MethodToTest();
        A.CallTo(_logger).Where(
                call => call.Method.Name == "Log" && call.GetArgument<LogLevel>(0) == LogLevel.Information) // Modify with your type of log
            .MustHaveHappened(1, Times.Exactly); // Modify with the number of times log is called
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For people finding this page, are using `FakeItEasy` and are looking for a way to validate the log action `object?[]` arguments passed to it can use this *(mind the horizontal scrollbar)*:

```
A.CallTo(logger).Where(call => call.Method.Name == nameof(ILogger.Log)
                                       && call.GetArgument<LogLevel>(0) == LogLevel.Error
                                       && (call.GetArgument<IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>>(2) ?? Array.Empty<KeyValuePair<string, object>>()).Any(e => e.Value.Equals(orderId))
                                       && call.GetArgument<Exception>(3) == exception)
            .MustHaveHappened(1, Times.Exactly);
```

I know it's a bit raw but one could easily muffle this away in an extension method.