How to simply inject ILogger<T> in dotnet unit tests?
I have a large number of constructors in a dotnet 8 project that all take ILogger<T> as a parameter.
I am now trying to unit test them, however I cannot work out how I can dynamically register such loggers with the standard Microsoft depedency injection framework.
How can I avoid having to manually register a logger for every type? Noting that I do want logging to actually occur so just supplying a null logger is not an option.
I don't want to have to do this:
var logger1 = new Mock<ILogger<Constructor1>>();
var logger2 = new Mock<ILogger<Constructor2>>();
var logger3 = new Mock<ILogger<Constructor3>>();
...
var loggern = new Mock<ILogger<Constructorn>>();


Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43425633/3957754

Does this answer your question? How to unit test with ILogger in ASP.NET Core

@JRichardsz Unfortunately both of those suggestions require you to manually register a logger for every type, so if I have 100 types thats 100 mocked loggers

You can register things generically now, so maybe that's an option: services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(YourMockImplementation<>));

@Reddog I get "CS7003 Unexpected use of an unbound generic name" when I try to do that

Which testing framework are you using? xUnit?

@Ortiga the standard one that Visual Studio 2022 uses, nUnit I believe?

You have a large number of constructors that all take ILogger as a parameter, and you want to dynamically register such loggers with the standard Microsoft dependency injection framework for unit testing.  This way, everything except the application bootstrapper is independent of the actual logger implementation, and changing the logging sink becomes straightforward. Check this example:
[Fact]
public void TestConstructor1()
{
    // Arrange
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole())
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var logger1 = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Constructor1>>();
    var constructor1 = new Constructor1(logger1);

    // Act
    // ... (perform your test actions)

    // Assert
    // ... (perform your assertions)
}

[Fact]
public void TestConstructor2()
{
    // Arrange
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole())
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var logger2 = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Constructor2>>();
    var constructor2 = new Constructor2(logger2);

    // Act
    // ... (perform your test actions)

    // Assert
    // ... (perform your assertions)
}``
// ... (similar tests for Constructor3, Constructor4, and so on)

}

I want to avoid having to to call GetService for every logger as you are suggesting - each logger is functionally the same, just logs to a file. This seems like an oversight in the DI framework...

I think, the way to go would be rely on dependency injection and amend it in scope of unit tests. For the loggers you could do the following:
On a nice place, you initialize or alter the service collection.
Note that multiple registrations are possible; if you reuse your configure methods of your app, you may have to remove the registrations before adding the below
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory>(new MyLoggerFactory());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerFactory, MyLoggerFactory>());
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger), typeof(Logger<object>)));
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>)));

This will instruct the service provider to fabricate a logger class for all inflight ILogger requests. Logger is just a wrapper for whatever the factory returns:
internal class MyLoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory
{
    public void AddProvider(ILoggerProvider provider)
    {
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return NullLogger.Instance;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

This dumb implementation returns a NullLoggger. If that is what you wanted, you could also use the NullLoggerFactory. This one enables you to provide one logger implementation (or mock) for any number of constructors:
[TestMethod]
public void TestMyService () 
{
   var serviceProvider = GoodPlace.GetServiceProvider();
   var myService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyService>(); // this will call MyLoggerFactory.CreateLogger(categoryName=FooBarCategory)...
}

with MyService:
internal class MyService 
{
  MyService (ILogger<FooBarCategory> logger,....){}
}

